# how to turn html inputs into php array

Tags: php, html, arrays, input

I am working on an application which, in the end, will produce a .CSV file. I have already found how to turn an array or arrays into a .CSV file, but I am having trouble figuring out the preceding step.

I have a bunch of html inputs in a form that will be sent to PHP, I am hoping to have one array consisting of all the input names (input name="example") and another array that consists of the values put into those fields by the end user.

In the end I was the CSV to be a product of both arrays. The first row being things like Height, Width, Depth, and the second row being 10 mm,20 mm,9 mm, etc etc.

I am wondering if a mixture of html classes and a foreach could be used, but I'm really not sure. Any help would be great! Thanks!!

Answer (score 10):

using the square bracket notation will convert these named fields into arrays, here are a few examples

```
<input name="array[]">
<input name="array[]">
<input name="array[]">

<input name="array[foo]">
<input name="array[bar]">

<input name="array[0][foo]">
<input name="array[0][bar]">
<input name="array[1][foo]">
<input name="array[1][bar]">
```

Then to get a quick preview of your data use var_dump() or print_r()

```
var_dump($_REQUEST['array']);
```

Comment: Oh great! Thank you so much. I'm a little new with arrays though (im sorry!). I just want to make sure I understand, am I able to name more than one array with my inputs? Like input 1-5 go to an array named "Awesome" and 5-10 go to "Donuts" or something.

Comment: Sure, the word "array" here can be replaced with your own name. Also if you're happy with this answer, please click the tick icon under the number next to this answer!